# Clojure: data.xml: create key named "xlink:href"

Tags: xml, clojure, xml-namespaces

### Context

I'm outputting a xml file from clojure using data.xml. I need to output the following line:

```
<use xlink:href="#whiskers" transform="scale(-1 1) translate(-140 0)" />
```

(We're drawing a cat in SVG).

Now, my try is something like:

```
(indent-str (element :use {:xlink:href "#whiskers",
               :transform "scale(-1 1) translate(-140 0)"}))
```

This fails because
    :xlink:href "#whiwksers"
  is apparently interpreted as:
    :xlink ,
    :href "#whiskers"

### Question

How do I create a clojure symbol to output "xlink:href" as a field for data.xml?

### Edit

I have tried:
    (keyword "xlink:href")

still same error. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an error here. If I do an `emit` on your `element` call the output shows up at `xlink:href="#whiskers"`.

Comment: I'm outputting with indent-str

Comment: @stand: emit works. I believe indent-str has a bug. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Ok, I discovered that `indent-str` does work as long as you construct xml with namespace declarations. Learned something today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an error here.

```
(def e (element :use {:xlink:href "#whiskers",
          :transform "scale(-1 1) translate(-140 0)"}))

(println (emit-str e))
=> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><use xlink:href="#whiskers" transform="scale(-1 1) translate(-140 0)"></use>
```

The `indent-str` function has a problem though:

```
(println (indent-str e))
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xlink" for attribute "xlink:href" 
associated with an element type "use" is not bound.
```

So it appears `clojure.data.xml` is namespace aware. Let's try this:

```
(def e-the-sequel (element :use {:xmlns:xlink "http://testing", 
                                 :xlink:href "#whiskers",
                                 :transform "scale(-1 1) translate(-140 0)"}))

(println (indent-str e-the-sequel))
=> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<use xmlns:xlink="http://testing" xlink:href="#whiskers" 
     transform="scale(-1 1) translate(-140 0)"/>
```

That's better. If anything, I guess you could argue that `emit-str` is wrong because it didn't throw an exception.

Comment: I wrote an ill-formed, unclear question. You did the research + inferred the problem + provided a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(element :use {:xlink/href "#whiskers",
               :transform "scale(-1 1) translate(-140 0)"})
```